# Div table not working

Tags: html

So What I am trying to do is put two textareas next to one another, and I tried to do this using div tables, but the table and its parts are shoved into the top left corner, so what am I doing wrong? is there a better way to do this?

```html
<head>
  <title>Lost</title>
  <style>
    * {
      padding: 0px;
      margin: 0px;
      border: 1px solid white;
    }
    
    body {
      background: black;
    }
    
    textarea {
      border: 1px solid white;
      background: black;
      width: 50%;
      height: 500px;
    }
    
    #table {
      display: table;
      width: auto;
    }
    
    #tr {
      display: table-row;
      width: auto;
    }
    
    #tc {
      display: table-column;
      width: 50%
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="table">
    <div id="tr">
      <div id="tc"><textarea readonly></textarea></div>
      <div id="tc"><textarea readonly></textarea></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <body>
    <script>
    </script>
```

Comment: Why not use `<table></table>`?

Comment: okay that worked, thx for helping a noob

Comment: @DavidAngulo Because that's semantically incorrect

Answer (score 0):

You can (better) use `flexbox` to solve this issue. With just a few lines it will solve the problem being a semantically correct implementation:

```
.box {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.box-textarea {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
}
```

Read more about [flexbox at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox).
Also, please make sure you've added `box-sizing: border-box;` to your code, otherwise the width will be `100% + 1px` because of the border.

```html
<head>
  <title>Lost</title>
  <style>
    * {
      padding: 0px;
      margin: 0px;
      border: 1px solid white;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    body {
      background: black;
    }
    
    textarea {
      border: 1px solid white;
      background: black;
      width: 100%;
      height: 500px;
    }
    
    .box {
      width: 100%;
      display: flex;
      flex-flow: row wrap;
    }
    
    .box-textarea {
      flex: 0 0 50%;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="box-textarea"><textarea readonly></textarea></div>
    <div class="box-textarea"><textarea readonly></textarea></div>
  </div>

  <body>
    <script>
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can surely use Flexbox as @Roy suggested.

"display: table-column" does NOT provide a mechanism for making columnar layouts (e.g. newspaper pages with multiple columns, where content can flow from one column to the next).

Rather, "table-column" ONLY sets attributes that apply to corresponding cells within the rows of a table

Use "table-cell" if it's the one you're expecting

[W3 Tables](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html)

```html
<head>
  <title>Lost</title>
  <style>
    * {
      padding: 0px;
      margin: 0px;
      border: 1px solid white;
    }
    
    body {
      background: black;
    }
    
    textarea {
      border: 1px solid white;
      background: black;
      height: 500px;
    }
    
    #table {
      display: table;
    }
    
    #tr {
      display: table-row;
    }
    
    #tc {
      display: table-cell;
      width: 50%
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="table">
    <div id="tr">
      <div id="tc"><textarea readonly></textarea></div>
      <div id="tc"><textarea readonly></textarea></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <body>
    <script>
    </script>
```